# JTable, make cell text multiline

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable where each cell occupy the same amount of space, but somethimes happen that text doesn't fit well inside cell, so i can't read entire content.
There's a way to adapt each table row height for show correctly all its content?
So each table row could have different height, and the maximum heigth o row is the minimum height to contain thew most long text

Comment: http://blog.botunge.dk/post/2009/10/09/JTable-multiline-cell-renderer.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965023/how-to-wrap-lines-in-a-jtable-cell

Comment: See `TextAreaRenderer` presented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20339015/1795530) that uses a `JTextArea` with line wrap active in order to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the row height individually.
When any value is changed, call this code:

```
int height = table.getRowHeight(row);
int newHeight  = table.prepareRenderer(table.getCellRenderer(row, column), row, column).getPreferredSize().height;
if (newHeight > height) {
    height = newHeight;
}
table.setRowHeight(row, rowHeight);
```